# How to prove that every set in a sigma ring is a subset of a countable union of sets in it generator?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

One of the "Remarks" in our lecture notes says that if $\mathcal G$ is non-empty family of sets and $\sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)$ is the sigma ring generated by $\mathcal G$, then every set in $\sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)$ is a subset of countable union of sets in $\mathcal G$. Why is this remark true.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
\mathfrak X:=\{A: A \text{ is contained in a countable union of sets in } \mathcal G\}
$$
Observe that

- $\emptyset\in\mathfrak{X}$
- $\mathfrak{X}$ is closed under countable unions.
- $\mathfrak X$ is closed under differences (in fact, if $B\subset A\in \mathfrak X$, then $B\in\mathfrak X$).
- $\mathcal G\subset \mathfrak{X}$

Do you see how to complete the argument?

Comment: Sorry I don't see it. Can you explain more please.

Comment: @user3879021 $\mathfrak{X}$ is a $\sigma$-ring containing $\mathcal G$, hence $\sigma_R(\mathcal G)\subset \mathfrak{X}$.

Comment: Do I need to show that $\mathfrak X\subset \sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)$ too (i.e $\mathfrak X=\sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)$)? or is $\sigma_{\mathcal R}(\mathcal G)\subset \mathfrak X$ enough?

Comment: For your purposes of showing that "Every set in $\sigma_R(\mathcal G)$ has property blah" then it suffices to argue that $\sigma_R(\mathcal G)\subset\mathfrak X$. Of course, you can modify $\mathfrak X$ to be $\mathfrak X:=\{A\in \sigma_R(\mathcal G): A \text{ is contained in a countable union of sets in } \mathcal G\}$, in which case the four properties I listed above are still true, and we now also have $\sigma_R(\mathcal G)=\mathfrak X$. With the original definition of $\mathfrak X$, this need not hold: every subset of $\mathbb R$ is covered by a countable union of open sets.

Comment: For the third property: How to show that $\mathfrak X$ is closed under differences if $B\not\subset A \in \mathfrak X$?

Comment: So If $A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and $B\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$ where $A_n,B_n$ are sets in $\mathcal G$. I don't set how $A|B\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$ where $C_n$ are sets in $\mathcal G$.

Comment: @user3879021 If $A,B\in \mathfrak X$, say $A\subset\bigcup_n A_n$ with $A_n\in\mathcal G$, then $A\setminus B\subset A\subset \bigcup_n A_n$.